# Ordering FieldInfos

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, reflection

I am doing encoding and decoding using reflection.
when I read the this.GetType().Getfields(), in some machines it is returned in a random order, I need to order them back to do the encoding and decoding correctly.

Can I sort the array returned from this.GetType().GetFields()  using FieldInfo.FieldHandle
Like this :

```
        FieldInfo[] infos = GetType().GetFields();
        Array.Sort(infos, delegate(FieldInfo first, FieldInfo second)
        {
            return first.FieldHandle.Value.ToInt32().CompareTo(second..Value.ToInt32());
        });
```

is it the correct way.
I mean Now it is give me correct ordering, but i don't know if it will do every time I call it(timing or time of processing issues).

is there any problem may happen in the future from this code.

## my question is about using "FieldHandle" in ordering.

## if it is not stable what can I use instead of it.

Regards,

Comment: What is the definition of the SortFields method?

Comment: What is 'correct' for you? Ie which orde do you want?

Comment: Phoog : I replace sortFilds with its definition.

Comment: Christian Horsdal : Now it is give me correct ordering, but i don,t know if it will do every time I call it(timing or time of processing issues .

Comment: I don't think sorting by the `FieldHandle` will give you consistent results between executions as it is **internal metadata**. Why do you want to sort the fields?

Comment: Dennis Roche : I am working on encoding and decoding, the order is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler way would be to use Linq:

```
FieldInfo[] infos = typeof(string).GetFields()
   .OrderBy(fi => fi.FieldHandle.Value.ToInt32()).ToArray();
```

But remember that the FieldHandle isn't necessarily a stable or meaningful field to sort by.

EDIT: I see you're asking about using FieldHandle to sort by, in general. In that case, the answer is YES, you WILL have problems with it in the future. The FieldHandle is a pointer to a structure in memory. This memory location is RANDOMLY allocated. Every time you run your program, you'll get a different set of FieldHandles, and your sorting will be different. This isn't a unique and persistent ID of the field, it's just a memory pointer.

What are you trying to accomplish with this sorting? Maybe we can suggest some alternatives.

Comment: I am doing encoding and decoding using reflection.

Comment: Encoding and decoding of what? Are you talking about encrypting/decrypting? Why would you need the fields sorted for that?

Comment: I mean Encapsulation (get certain class fields, add headers to the there values, send the packet to certain machine , the machine will remove the headers, understand the values then reply in the same way).
so if I send the second field value replaced with the first field value, the machine will corrupted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still unclear on what you're trying to achieve. All the things you've mentioned here don't seem to have anything to do with reflection or fieldhandles. How are you sending this data to a different machine? 
It seems you're trying to define a Data Contract when sending messages between machines. The best way to do that is to define your class with the [DataContract] attribute, and add [DataMember(Order=X)] attributes on the members themselves. This will ensure that the message format will be fixed. But we're missing several steps here.

Comment: I was trying to use attributes before, but I have more than 200 class. So I keep it as Plan B.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you need a consistent order. Most communications frameworks (WCF, remoting, etc) serialize the data between the two services in a way that isn't order-dependent. If you're doing the serialization yourself for some reason, why not just sort by the field's Name, which isn't likely to change, and which will be consistent between calls and machines.

Comment: I am developing a client SW that reads data from a meter working on DLMS protocol. DLMS protocol use BER and A-xdr encoding formats. A-xdr have a structure called Sequence, which have fields that should be encoded in the same order. For example:

Comment: Get-Response-Normal ::= SEQUENCE 
{ 
    invoke-id-and-priority                  Invoke-Id-And-Priority, 
    result                                  Get-Data-Result 
} 

this structure is defined in both the client and the meter and should be sent to the meter in this exact order. So the "result" field cannot be the first field. if I send it first, the meter will understand it as "invoke-id-and-priority" field.

Comment: Ok, things are a bit clearer now.
You have a hard-coded, predefined format and order for your fields. This cannot be inferred from the fields themselves via reflection: it's not stored in the class metadata. What you probably need to do is write a serializer of your own, which encodes this specific business logic. Either hard-coded, or by reading the a-xdr schema and looking for matching fields and rendering them in-order. Reflection won't help you order them.